# why eventemitter is fired although the event handler is not invoked explicitly

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below code is from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_event_loop.htm . In that code, data_received event is fired in the definition of connectHandler() function. Although the connectHandler() function is not invoked, data_received event is fired. How is that possible?

```
// Import events module
var events = require('events');
// Create an eventEmitter object
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

// Create an event handler as follows
var connectHandler = function connected() {
   console.log('connection succesful.');

   // Fire the data_received event 
   eventEmitter.emit('data_received');
}

// Bind the connection event with the handler
eventEmitter.on('connection', connectHandler);

// Bind the data_received event with the anonymous function
eventEmitter.on('data_received', function(){
   console.log('data received succesfully.');
});

// Fire the connection event 
eventEmitter.emit('connection');

console.log("Program Ended.");
```

Output :

```
connection succesful.
data received succesfully.
Program Ended.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Fire the connection event 
eventEmitter.emit('connection');
```

Here you should observe that a 'connection' event is being fired which is bound to connectHandler function thus invoking further events.

Comment: Oh my nonseeing eyes!